# R package - tidyselect install fails

Tags: r, r-package, tidyselect

Trying to install tidyselect R pacakge on amazon linux, it fails with ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyselect’. Please guide me on installing this package, kindly refer the below output,

```
bash-4.2# /usr/bin/R CMD INSTALL tidyselect_0.2.5.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘tidyselect’ ...
** package ‘tidyselect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c combine_variables.cpp -o combine_variables.o
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o tidyselect.so RcppExports.o combine_variables.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/lib64/R/library/tidyselect/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.2 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyselect’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/tidyselect’
bash-4.2#
```

Error message

```
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.2 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyselect’
```

Comment: Your `rlang` is outdated. Current cran version is `0.3.0.1`. Update `rlang`.

Comment: update `rlang` with: `install.packages("rlang")`